# Generating model one-to-one field with django-autofixtures

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create fake data for my model which is linked to the *auth.User*. I'm running Python 3.7 with Django 2.1 django-autofixture 0.12.1:

**models.py**

```
Class Person(models.Model):
      user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
      about = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

**autofixtures.py**

```
Class PersonGenerator(AutoFixture):
      field_values = {
        'user':InstanceGenerator(autofixture=UserFixture(User)),
        'about': LoremGenerator(max_length=200)
      }
register(Person,PersonGenerator)
```

Then I run the autofixtures file to register my generator

```
py manage.py shell
>>> exec(open('myapp/autofixtures.py').read())
>>> exit()

py manage.py loadtestdata myapp.Person:50
```

I've got the following error message:

```
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "D:\..\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "D:\..\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "D:\..\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 316, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "D:\..\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 353, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "c:\..\local\programs\python\python37-32\Lib\contextlib.py", line 74, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwds)
  File "D:\..\env\lib\site-packages\autofixture\management\commands\loadtestdata.py", line 225, in handle
    autofixture.create(model, count, **kwargs)

  File "D:\..\env\lib\site-packages\autofixture\__init__.py", line 136, in create
    return autofixture.create(count, **create_kwargs)
  File "D:\..\env\lib\site-packages\autofixture\base.py", line 554, in create
    instance = self.create_one(commit=commit, **kwargs)
  File "D:\..\env\lib\site-packages\autofixture\base.py", line 501, in create_one
    self.process_field(instance, field)
  File "D:\..\env\lib\site-packages\autofixture\base.py", line 400, in process_field
    value = self.get_value(field)
  File "D:\..\env\lib\site-packages\autofixture\base.py", line 396, in get_value
    value = generator()
  File "D:\..\env\lib\site-packages\autofixture\generators.py", line 71, in __call__
    return self.get_value()
  File "D:\..\env\lib\site-packages\autofixture\generators.py", line 67, in get_value
    value = self.generate()
  File "D:\..\env\lib\site-packages\autofixture\generators.py", line 535, in generate
    return self.autofixture.create()[0]

File "D:\..\env\lib\site-packages\autofixture\base.py", line 554, in create
        instance = self.create_one(commit=commit, **kwargs)
File "D:\..\env\lib\site-packages\autofixture\base.py", line 526, in create_one
        self.process_m2m(instance, field)
File "D:\..\env\lib\site-packages\autofixture\base.py", line 413, in process_m2m
        return self.process_field(instance, field)
File "D:\..\env\lib\site-packages\autofixture\base.py", line 403, in process_field
        setattr(instance, field.name, value)
File "D:\..\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py", line 537, in __set__
        % self._get_set_deprecation_msg_params(),


TypeError: Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use groups.set() instead.
```

How can it be M2M set when my relationship is one-to-one?

Answer (score 0):

So Django 2 does not allow creating foreign key without saving the instance first. I switched to [factory boy](https://github.com/FactoryBoy/factory_boy) and use their SubFactory feature for this and it works.

Answer (score 0):

to fix error with many to many fields for django-autofixture in django 2 you can do it like this

```
class News(models.Model):
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)

news = AutoFixture(News).Create(1, commit=False)
news.save()
news.categories.set([AutoFixture(Category).create_one()])
```